# Is an "Ateret Chatan" only for Chassanim?

Tags: marriage, transactions, tallit-gadol

I really like the kind of atara for a tallis that has rows of metal squares (like [this](https://tzitzit.tallit-shop.com/ateret-chatan/)). On this link, it is called an "Ateret Chatan" and the description says "A popular addition to a tallis for a chassan at a fraction of the price of silver."

I have been married for a number of years and have never worn such an atara. I would like to buy one for myself, but I'm not sure if this is somehow presumptuous or otherwise distasteful for someone who is not newly married. Is this kind of atara generally reserved for chassanim, or is it normal for anybody to buy one like it?

Comment: Not to be confused with https://www.sefaria.org/Sotah.49a.12?p2=Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.560.4

Comment: It could be the reason why people put silver atara is to show chashivos of the atafia and when one covers their head(see Aruch Hashulchan who was against the silver atara for this reason) which the common minhag is for only married men to cover their head with tallis.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) tallis-man and thanks for this first question. Can I recommend you take the [tour](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) to get a sense of how the site works?  Great to have you learn with us!